# JavaScript Regex Match Strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a small program that converts a string to a JavaScript variable. I am trying to figure out how to do this. I can't seem to figure out how to use .match...

Here is my code

```
function convertVariables(){

var matches = code.match(/@[^;]+/g);

    for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){

        code = code.replace(matches[i].substring(0, 1), "var ");
        console.log("Found one");

    }

}
```

If the input would be:

```
@somevariable = "some string";
@anothervariable = 12;
```

The output should be:

```
var somevariable = "some string";
var anothervariable = 12;
```

Comment: Can you give add an example of an input with its expected output to make it clearer what you are trying to do? You can pass a regex to `replace` and do it all in basically 1 call, instead of a `for` loop

Comment: I have added examples. @Rhumborl

Comment: You have a typo: `match` should be `matches` in the `for` condition. The rest seems fine.

Comment: I fixed the typo but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It works in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dp1ha1w1/

Comment: Oh! I just didn't save it. /.<

Comment: Don't practice bad programming habit's. That's a security risk and a design flaw

Comment: @JayHarris the question has no context whatsoever, how can you claim it to be a design/security flaw?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté If its a string that he made, its a design flaw, if its a string from a user's input its a security risk

Comment: You can't declare variables with dynamic names by prepending the `var` keyword to strings, it just can't be done that way

Comment: @JayHarris I see your point, though there are a million use cases where one can use such a context-free regex. For example, pre-processing a configuration file in Node.js.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté very true, but i assumed he was just practicing some code. 'Create a small program'

Comment: __code.replace(matches[i].substring(0, 1), "var ")__ is equivalent to __code.replace('@', 'var ')__, since the first character of every match is the 'at' sign.

So you don't even need regex.

Comment: @Paedolos I would do that but the @ symbol can be used differently like in a string. for example `@myemail = "blah@blah.com";` I wouldn't want it to change to `var myemail = "blahvar blah.com";`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @arjay07 You are right. What I was trying to say is that your code is actually doing that, as you are performing the replace on the entire 'code' variable, and not implicitly on the match.